# Some of the images are not coming after Publishing WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I have published my WPF application using ClickOnce publishing method. I ran the application on the client PC and I noticed that some of my images are not appearing e.g. Background images of Windows. I looked carefully and found out that one Sample.jpg Photo is properly showing inside the Image container which I've used for every record.

Same goes for another image n still coming. The problem I am not able to figure out why both these two images are coming and not the background one?

While creating the Application I have put all the images in a single Folder and all images are referenced from this single folder only.

I also tried by simply copying my project>BIN folder files to client machine and yes, all images are loaded properly without any issues. The problem is only coming in the publish version of my application.

Could anyone help me in this? are there any settings I should take care of while deploying the application? Or I should move them to any specific location?

Comment: Have you made sure that the **Build Action** of all the image files is set to `Resource` and that they are adressed by proper [Resource File Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly)?

Comment: What kind of URIs are you using to reference the images in your Xaml?  You should be using relative or absolute `pack` URIs, but keep in mind that `siteoforigin` pack URIs behave differently depending on whether your app was deployed through ClickOnce.

Answer (score 1):

Are your images Build Action property set to content and the Copy to Output directory property set to Copy always/Copy if newer?

Comment: This helped me when I set each image's Build Action property to Content and Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always.

I then changed the way that I was getting the file paths to a more relative way so that I could share my application with others. For example: ("/Images/")